# OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' makes \\n become invalid

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook

I tried to load a csv file into database using Python:

```
SQLCMD = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/v***/MySQLfiles/salaries.csv' \
INTO TABLE salaries.salaries \
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' \
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' \
IGNORE 1 ROWS"
```

When I run it, I got the error in line 4:

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

I know the error is related to `\\n` because it's black(I use Jupyter notebook) and other parts are all red.

I think the reason is because the double quote in this part:

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

This makes Python think the entire part ends here:

```
"LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/v***/MySQLfiles/salaries.csv' \
    INTO TABLE salaries.salaries \
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"
```

But `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` is a must, I need this part because some columns contain commas.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by the `"` in `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` ending the `SQLCMD` string. You could fix this by using a backslash to escape the quote, but it'd be easier to use a triple-quoted string to avoid having to escape the quotes altogether:

```
SQLCMD = """LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/v***/MySQLfiles/salaries.csv' 
INTO TABLE salaries.salaries 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS"""
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. :) By the way, why don't we need \ as a continue sign anymore at the end of each line after using """?

Comment: One of the purposes of triple-quoted strings (which can be made with either `"""` or `'''`) is to be a multi-line string, so you don't need to manually escape the ends of the lines.